# Prove or disprove the identity on $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I encountered a problem about the containing relations about the $\sigma$-algebras.
Let $<\mathcal{A}>$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.
Suppose for a collection of sets $\mathcal{C}$, and a set $Z$ we define $$\mathcal{C}\times Z := \{C\times Z; C\in \mathcal{C} \}, $$ where "$\times$" described in the set is the Cartesian product.
My problem is that do we have:   $$<\mathcal{C}\times Z> =  <\mathcal{C}> \times Z$$
holds? I strongly believe that they are the same, and proved the direction "$\subset$" above. So how to verify the other direction? Or is there anything wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It may help you to first show that any element of $\langle \mathcal{C}\times Z\rangle$ is of the form $S\times Z$, for some set $S$ (which happens to be  a member of $\langle \mathcal{C}\rangle$.)

Answer (score 1):

Had a huge misunderstanding. You're wanting to show something different than what I wrote in the comments. It's interesting.

The goal is to show that $\sigma(A \times Z) = \sigma(A) \times Z$, where $Z$ is just some set and $A$ is a collection of sets. First question is whether $\sigma(A) \times Z$ is a $\sigma$-algbera. The answer is yes, by properties of Cartesian product. Naturally we have $\sigma(A \times Z) \subseteq \sigma(A) \times Z$. Now let $\mathcal{M}$ be any other $\sigma$-algebra containing $A \times Z$. Then again just using some nice properties about products and unions/intersections/complements we have $\sigma(A) \times Z \subseteq \mathcal{M}$. Thus by minimality we get the result.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Unions

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Intersections

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_with_Complement

Comment: Could you be more rigorous? Because I tried and still cannot obtain the other containing relations.

Comment: Sure, which part do you want to see specifically?

Comment: Sorry for late reply for a whole month because I was busy those days. If you are still willing to answer, I'd like you to explain why $\sigma (A) \times Z \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ rigorously. I have just succeeded in the proof when $Z$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, in particular.